# Statistical analysis in R language

Tags: r, regression, modeling, roc

I have a few questions about statistical tests in R. I have a dependent variable Admitted, whose values could be either Yes or No and have 100 observations. When we train our model, we get results like No, No, Yes, No, No, Yes, Yes ...... for one algorithm such as Random Forest and similar type of results using SVM.

My question is which statistical test we can perform on this data so that we get one algorithm (RF) is statistically better than the other (SVM).

Thanks

Comment: Flagging as off-topic - this is about statistics, not programming. Also data cannot be parametric/non-parametric; methods may be classified that way. You need to read your text more closely.

Comment: very strange. when I post this in R language forum, they say it is not about programming. When I post here, you say it is about programming. Even if it is off-topic, wouldn't it be nice if you answer just in one line than you complain in two lines.. Or at least, let the others to respond.

Comment: Hi, Neha unfortunately I have to say it is off-topic because your question is about statistics, has nothing to do with R or programming and is simply too broad. Parametric means you more or less have an idea of what distribution the data follows, so you can have parametric test like poisson,t, binomial etc.. Non parametric test are distribution free and can also include chi-square, wilcoxon etc. So the answer is, R doesn't help you with whether it's parametric or not.

Comment: And for your second question, you cannot compare ROC values using a statistical test.

Comment: So how can we then compare the results when we get the results in ROC? Can we do it using confusion matrix? I have read a paper that compared ROC values and performed the Friedman test as well as bayesian test.

Comment: Data are neither parametric nor nonparametric so the premise of your opening paragraph is wrong. What do you mean when you say that?

Comment: One reason your question gets bounced around is its implicit premise that statistical analysis and coding in `R` are the same thing. Far from it! For it to be on-topic on SO, it would have to pose an explicit programming problem, using a minimal reproducible example. For it to be on-topic here on CV, it needs to indicate that you want a particular *statistical* question answered, regardless of what programming languages you might prefer. I think we can interpret it in the latter sense, so it is likely on topic here, but be prepared for some close votes from readers who see only the `R` focus.

Comment: I am sorry for any confusion. I have edited the question and make it more easy.